# "schemas" are empty although connection to database established

Tags: database, eclipse, mariadb

I've installed the Eclipse plugin `data development` in Eclipse to view my MariaDB (named "mydatabase"), hosted locally, in my project.

I've installed  `MariaDB java connector` from https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/java/latest/

I've then created a new connection, chosen `Generic GDBC` and in the config I've set:

```
Database: mydatabase
URL: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mydatabase
user name: root
password: mypassword
```

I've specified in the tab for "Driver template" the Java connector that I've downloaded.

In the end, the connection is established, and the name of my database appears in the `data source explorer`.

The problem is: under my database, I see the structure with "schemas" as a folder, but when I click on it, it's empty.

**EDIT**: the tree that I see:

```
folder "mydatabase"
   └--- folder "Authorization IDs" (empty)
   └--- folder "Catalogs"
           |--- folder "Information_schema"
           |         └--- folder "schemas" (empty)
           └--- folder "mydatabase"
                     └--- folder "schemas" (empty)
```

Comment: I don't know Eclipse plugin, but mariadb has databases (catalog) but no schema, so it might seem normal

Comment: Thanks. I've got a "Catalogs" folder also in fact! I've edited my post to be more clear.